# Covenient way to generate HTML page from many complex javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, express

I want to generate a HTML page from many javascript objects then display it to the user.

Fox example:

```js
var mybutton = {
  id: 'button_1',
  x: '0',
  y: '0',
  width: '100',
  height: '50',
  state: 'on',
  onColor: '#ff0000',
  offColor: '#00ff00',
  base: 'page1.node1',
  ...
}
```

should be converted to

```html
<rect id="button_1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="#ff0000" .../>
```

and then added to a html document. There are many other elements (with different types) in this document.
Eventually, this document is saved to a file o rendered in the browser.

The main problem is that I do not know how many elements there are in the doccument, what types there are, ... at design time. It is all loaded from a configuration file.

It is tedious to iterate through object array and generate conrresponding svg element by string processing like:

```js
var document;
...
 
if(mybutton instanceof button) {
  var element = '<rect id="' + mybutton.id + '" ' + mybutton.x + '" ' + ...;
  document +=element;
}
```

Templating is not helpful in this case because my document does not fit any templates. Its content is highly dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel if I were you. We use extJS to do just that. Check out the documentation over at [www.sencha.com](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/). We don't use the MVC portion of extJS, just the javascript api that allows us to define widgets and they automatically get displayed on the page.

Comment: OP question is not about ExtJS.

Comment: extJS is not helpful in my case.